# Regex matching longest with OR condition in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract a part of a string where multiple patterns are set in a regex and using a condition OR ("|") to test them.
Unfortunately my first condition is included in the second one and split my result into 2 groups instead of one.

I'm using C# basic System Regex.

**Here an exemple of what I want :**

My string : abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz

My regex : [a-m]+|[a-z]+

**The result is 2 matches :**

(1) : abcdefghijklm

(2) : opqrstuvwxyz

I want to get the whole string as a match, even in a (3) result

Is there a way to do it without switching the 2 conditions ?

Sincerely,
Peaceandlove25

Comment: Try this regex `[a-z]+`.

Comment: With your current syntax that's not possible. Regex will move forward to find matches (apart from a lookbehind but that doesn't match). So after your first condition matches it won't move the cursor back for the other match.

Comment: @Max My exemple is a simplified version of what I'm trying to reach, let me explain : I sure could have done [a-z]+ but in my case [a-m] is an other complex regex

Comment: regex `[a-m]+` does not match order only that the character is in that range. so `aamm` wil also match

Comment: Make sure the alternative you want to prioritize comes first - this is the only correct way. The real life solution might be quite different as this is an XY problem right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to split the regex. Regex always moves forward. Once a match has been found, it doesn't look back. That's why the second group doesn't start at 'a', but at 'o'.

You might be able to do the regex twice, since you are fine if a third-match will be found.

```
var regexFirstCheck = [a-m]+
var regexSecondCheck = [a-z]+
```

Your business logic can combine the results, so you can end up with 2 or 3 matches:

```
1: abcdefghijklm
2: abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
```

If you need the o-z match, you can use the regex you provided, or just create another step. This might increase readability:

```
var regexFirstCheck = [a-m]+
var regexSecondCheck = [o-z]+
var regexThirdCheck = [a-z]+

1: abcdefghijklm
2: opqrstuvwxyz
3: abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
```